# Experiencing Python Print Syntax Error in Tweepy

Tags: python, syntax-error, tweepy

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Tweepy. I keep getting an 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' on the print line, and I'm not sure why.

Relevant Code

```
for tweet in api.search(q = 'python', lang="en", rpp=10):
    print(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")
```

Comment: Are you using an older Python version that does not support f-strings?

Comment: I'm in Python 3.8.2

Comment: Strange comment edit from Python 2.7 to 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably using a python version that doesn't support f-strings possibly < 3.6

Answer (score 0):

if python 2.7
then use format method

```
print "%s:%s" %(tweet.user.name,tweet.text)
```

if python 3
This formatting should works

```
print("{}:{}".format(tweet.user.name,tweet.text))
```

```
print(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")
```